# Android BackStack NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, back-stack

I have a problem that I've been dealing with for the last couple o days and don't seem to find an answer to it.

Description : I have a main activity which contains a navigation drawer. Each item of the navigation drawer (when clicked) creates a fragment. In that fragment, there is a listView of objects, which creates other fragments when clicked. In those fragments i have another listView of objects which opens other fragments. In other words, there series of fragment that open other fragment. Something like this:

http://s22.postimg.org/pddo5gsv5/backstack.png

In order to be able to get back to each fragment, I've implemented the addToBackstack("string") method.

My question is, how can I implement correct backstack for my application so that when i click a navigation Drawer item, all the fragments that have been added to backstack are cleared, without the one that the navigation Drawer item opens.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you !

***EDIT***

Ok, it seems I managed to figure it out. Considering what advices i received from the replies, here's the solution I came up with:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (count != 0) {
        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry = getFragmentManager()
                .getBackStackEntryAt(
                        getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1);
        if (backEntry.getName() == NAVIGATION) {
            finish();
        } else
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

To put it in words: First, i added a backstack entry even for the top level fragments, given them a specific tag. The I have overridden the Activity's back button function so that when the last backstack entry is a top-level fragment to finish the activity (so that it not simply detach the fragment from activity, living it empty). Otherwise, if the last entry isn't an top-level fragment, execute a popBackStack.
PS: All non-top-level fragments are added to the backstack with a different tag then the top-level one. Also, i had to do a POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE in the navigation Drawer's click listener.

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Thank you all for the advices and hopefully this EDIT help other users.

Comment: More and more I work with the drawer layout I think the `iosched` example app did the best possible thing. Multiple activities each have their own content fragment and their own drawer with preselected section, so you work only with activity stack and don't have to worry about fragment stack. "This is my wisdom to you."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to solve your problem:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(fragment_tag)
                    .commit();
```

In order to make the code above work, you have to create the fragments dynamically. As **hardcoded fragments cannot be replaced**. To do that, you can create a container (FrameLayout etc.) which in our example has the id *fragment_container*. Then, the code above will add the fragment in the container dynamically. Finally, you have to pass as parameter in the *addToBackStack* method the *fragment_tag*. That means, that this transaction will be added in the back stack. And finally, in order to get it from the backstack you have to use the code below:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(fragment_tag, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE));
```

The POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE flag, insures that "all matching entries will be consumed until one that doesn't match is found or the bottom of the stack is reached. Otherwise, all entries up to but not including that entry will be removed."

Comment: What exactly do you mean by creating the fragments dynamically ? The way I create fragments is by making their xml layout and then I inflate them in the java code. After that i use the .add and .replace methods to add them to the activity.
And I use the exact method you wrote above, but then, on the onClick button of my navigation Drawer listener i get some null pointer exception on some elements of the fragments I want to pop from the backstack.

Comment: @Phantom I mean that you cannot replace a fragment that is statically placed in an xml layout file. You need to create them programmatically.

Comment: But isn't that somehow against Android Fundamentals, having to create the layout of the fragment by code ? I know that it can be done, but is much harder and more time consuming this way.
Also, I create the fragments statically with an xml file and I can replace them without any problem. The only problem that I have is that when I try to remove them from the backstack in the navigation drawer click listener, I get null pointer exception from them and I don't know why, because I don't want to access them, I only want to remove the from the backstack

Comment: @Phantom I wouldn't say that it's against android fundamentals, by I would agree that is more difficult to maintain it. Use the addToBackStack(null) and don't pass any tag. I think that this could work.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't because I've tried it. The same error with the null pointer exception from some elements in the fragments is shown. And, again, I don't know why because I don't access those fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the fragment backstack by using something like:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack("string", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

and then you can `addToBackstack` and `commit` as usual. [More info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(int,%20int)).

A code snippet that shows the way I normally use it in navigation drawers:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
if(clearBackStack) {
    fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
if(!clearBackStack) {
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
}
ft.commit();
```

Comment: This is the exact method I'm currently using (I added all the fragments with the same string in the backstack). Where exactly should I put this function ? Cause where it is right now (in the DrawerItemClicklListener I get null pointer exceptions from some elements of the fragments I want to pop from the backstack

Comment: Added an example, it could be placed in your listener. The NullPointerExceptions might be related to other issues, you could double check your fragment lifecycle.

Comment: When an element in the navigation drawer is clicked, I set it to true to indicate that we are accessing a new "top level" fragment (first fragment column in the picture you provided). Otherwise it's set to false to add a fragment to the current backstack.

Comment: I've just realized, you don't want `addToBackstack` for a top level fragment. I'm modifying the example, sorry for the confusion.